# How do I plot a pie chart over a frame/border in matplotlib, using zorder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, z-order

I am trying to make a pie chart plot in matplotlib and create a black border around it that covers the chart, the legend, and the title. I tried using plt.box(), but the current radius of the pie chart is larger than default, so the box does not fit well.

Next I tried a few suggestions from other SO questions, like using set_zorder and [p.set_zorder(10) for p in patches1], but I am still not getting the correct order.

Here is my code and the image it is producing. Thanks!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# fig = plt.figure()
# ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.add_axes((0.5, 0, 1, 1)).set_zorder(0)

patches1, texts1 = ax.pie(pharm_vc, radius=1.5, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'w', 'linewidth': 1.5, 'linestyle': 'solid'}
  , textprops={'color': 'k', 'fontsize': 10, 'fontweight': 'bold'}, labels=pharm_vc, labeldistance=1.05
  )

[p.set_zorder(10) for p in patches1]

ax.legend(labels=pharm_vc.index, loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1.50, 1.25)).set_zorder(10)

plt.show()
```

[image: Pie Chart plot]

Comment: It's hard to guess what exactly you want to achieve. Also, your code doesn't seem to create the image shown.  Maybe using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(linewidth=4, edgecolor='black')`, leaving out `fig.add_axes()` and adding `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` would get you further? Note that everything that uses the same `ax` is drawn before anything on an other `ax`. The `zorder` of an ax defines the order in which these are drawn. The `zorder` of other elements defines the order in which the individual elements inside one ax are drawn.

Comment: Sorry, I had updated the chart to display all the elements clearly. I just fixed the code to reflect that update. I just want the pie chart and legend to display in front of the white rectangle, using zorder. I think all elements use the same ax. Unless fig is a separate ax?

Comment: Ok, I tried the linewidth=4, edgecolor='black'. That worked. Would you happen to know how to do it using zorder only?

Comment: You didn't remove `fig.add_axes(...)`?? `ax.pie` default hides the axes.  Your question about `zorder` is very confusing. A `fig` isn't an `ax`, it is a container for all axes inside it.

Comment: The new `ax` object you created by `fig.add_axes()` can be made invisible again via `fig.axes[-1].set_visible(False)` or its background set transparent via `fig.axes[-1].set_facecolor('none')`. But, better do not create it. Please read again what I wrote about `zorder` in the first comment.